# Rails Save CSV Object to Paperclip File?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, paperclip

This is odd, but i am working with an API library that returns a `CSV::Table` object.

I am now trying to persist with paperclip.

```
tempfile = Tempfile.new([report_id, '.csv'])

CSV.open(backup, 'w') do |writer|
  csvtable = APICSVFETCHER.get_report(report_id)
  csvtable.to_a.each do |row|
    writer << row
  end
end
# paperclip method archive
self.archive = File.open(backup)
self.save!
```

Now this is fine, and it works.

But it seems like an odd way of saving a CSV object to a paperclip file.

I want to do something like:

```
self.archive = CSV.parse(APICSVFETCHER.get_report(report_id))
self.save!
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. Using a StringIO with additional attributes and values that paperclip needs.

```
class FileFromString < StringIO
  attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type; 
end

def fake_file report_id

  ff = FileFromString.open(APICSVFETCHER.get_report(report_id).to_csv)  
  ff.original_filename = report_id.to_s
  ff.content_type = 'text/csv'
  ff

end
```

Then use it.

```
self.archive = fake_file(report_id)
self.save!
```